# Objc <-> Swift compatibility for swift generic function

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Following function:

```
func popTo<ViewController>(viewController: ViewController.Type, animated: Bool) where ViewController: UIViewController
```

works with Swift only. I need to use this method in objc code. After reconsidering a bunch of options, I'm not sure what to do to make it compatible with objc. Probably the easiest option would be to create another function somehow exposing that to objc, but I'm not sure what solution is the most proper here to handle it.

Comment: Do you need the generic placeholder? Just say `@objc func popTo(viewController: UIViewController.Type, animated: Bool)` otherwise.

Comment: @Hamish Unfortunately, I do need that, that's why I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: How are you using it? Can you please show us the implementation?

Comment: @Hamish That's quite a long chain :/ Generally at some point it goes back to swift implementation, but due to old implementation written in objc it goes to objc as well.

Comment: Ah okay, but is it possible to show how the generic placeholder is used? Can't the `viewController` metatype (in my above suggestion) be used directly instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
func popTo<ViewController>(viewController: ViewController.Type, animated: Bool) where ViewController: UIViewController
```

is equivalent of

```
func popTo(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

that it is "objc-able"

Comment: No, it's different. The first one passes the type, so that you eg. write `popTo(MyViewControllerSubclass)` rather than `popTo(myInstanceOfMyViewControllerSubclass)` as in your code. It's quite important when you don't have an instance.